# How to enable permission to access account information while using api key?

Tags: python, evernote

I'm a newbie for web app developing. Here's my question - When I run the django sample included in the evernote SDK for python. There's a authorization page describes what my application be able to do, and what's my application NOT able to do. Just like the 1st attached file.
[image]
    My question is - How can I enable the permission to access the account information when user authorizes the web app??? (Like the remain bandwidth and next cycle start day). The 2nd attached file is what I working on recently. I hope user can get their own account remain bandwidth and next cycle start day when they visit the web app.
[image]

Update @ 20180320:
I just apply a new FULL ACCESS API Key, and I got the new permission like this:
[image]

But Access Account Information permission is still forbidden.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Evernote API key permissions can be adjusted upon request. Go to https://dev.evernote.com/support/, click on 'Activate API key', fill out the form and in the comments provide information on what extra permission scopes you need.

Comment: I've sent my request on the page you mentioned, however, Evernote not reply my request yet. Once the result is just what I expected. I'll tag your reply as the answer, thanks a lot. :)

Comment: Hi, Igor, I've successfully demo my idea on my local PC. Thanks a lot. I'll  request to active once I done the all modifications.